# dot doesn't recognize any formats

Tags: graphics, package-management

My installation of [graphviz 2.36.0-0ubuntu3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/graphviz) doesn't seem to support *any* output formats:

```
$ dot -Tpng
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:
$ dot -Tsvg 
Format: "svg" not recognized. Use one of:
```

I.o.w., the list of output formats is simply empty. Do I need to install some extra packages? The package doesn't recommend or suggest anything that looks like support for additional formats.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. Issuing just a bare `dot` command explains the problem:

```
$ dot
There is no layout engine support for "dot"
Perhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's privileges) to register the plugins?
```

So, I did

```
sudo dot -c
```

which, judging from the output of just `dot -c`, writes a configuration file to `/usr/lib/graphviz/config6`. Clearly a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz/+bug/1349026) in the package's install script.

Comment: My `config6` file wasn't empty so I renamed it and ran `sudo dot -c` again and this fixed the problem. Perhaps the `config6` was corrupt?